# Making Json-Rpc calls from java

Tags: java, json, rpc

I'm writing a java application which runs on the local machine, it needs to interact with another program (also running on the local machine), the other program has a JSON RPC API which is the best way to interact with it. However, in googling around I found a lot of libraries for exposing JSON RPC methods from a java application but nothing good on how to call a remote JSON method. How would I do this?

The two things I'm looking for are:

1. A way to create new JSON objects
   to send
2. A way to connect to the
   other program and send my response
3. A way to decode the JSON response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interacting with JSON text in Java, see [JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/).  Use this for building JSON request objects and serializing them to text as well as de-serializaing the response from the RPC server.

Is this over HTTP or a plain TCP connection?  If the former, use [`HTTPClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).  If the latter, just open a socket and use its I/O streams.

Answer (score 3):

I have found couple of very good Java JSON-RPC libraries. Both are free. [JSON-RPC 2](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0.html) is of really high quality, and I can also recommend some of his other works. [jsonrpc4j](http://code.google.com/p/jsonrpc4j/) seems complete, but I have not used it. Both of these libraries solve several problems, so that you do not have to deal with low level implementation.

In addition, [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is an awesome library for serializing Java objects into JSON. If you have a complicated API, it can help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some source examples and projects to look at to demonstrate how you might go about creating your own...

**1. A way to create new JSON objects to send**

```
    import java.util.UUID;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    protected JSONObject toJSONRequest(String method, Object[] params) throws JSONRPCException
        {
                //Copy method arguments in a json array
                JSONArray jsonParams = new JSONArray();
                for (int i=0; i<params.length; i++)
                {
                        if(params[i].getClass().isArray()){
                                jsonParams.put(getJSONArray((Object[])params[i]));
                        }
                        jsonParams.put(params[i]);
                }

                //Create the json request object
                JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
                try 
                {
                        jsonRequest.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().hashCode());
                        jsonRequest.put("method", method);
                        jsonRequest.put("params", jsonParams);
                }
                catch (JSONException e1)
                {
                        throw new JSONRPCException("Invalid JSON request", e1);
                }
                return jsonRequest;
        }
```

Source adapted from: https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/source/browse/trunk/android-json-rpc/src/org/alexd/jsonrpc/JSONRPCClient.java?r=47

Or using GSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

JsonObject req = new JsonObject();
req.addProperty("id", id);
req.addProperty("method", methodName);

JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
if (args != null) {
    for (Object o : args) {
        params.add(gson.toJsonTree(o));
    }
}
req.add("params", params);

String requestData = req.toString();
```

From *org/json/rpc/client/**JsonRpcInvoker.java*** of [json-rpc-client](https://code.google.com/p/json-rpc-client/)

**2. A way to connect to the other program and send my response**

Using HTTP, you could do the following:

```
URL url = new URL("http://...");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();

OutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = connection.getOutputStream();

    out.write(requestData.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new JsonRpcClientException("unexpected status code returned : " + statusCode);
    }
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Source adapted from *org/json/rpc/client/**HttpJsonRpcClientTransport.java*** of [json-rpc-client](https://code.google.com/p/json-rpc-client/)

**3. A way to decode the JSON response**

Read the HTTP response and then parse the JSON:

```
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
try {
    in = connection.getInputStream();
    in = new BufferedInputStream(in);

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int n;
    while ((n = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
        bos.write(buff, 0, n);
    }
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject resp = (JsonObject) parser.parse(new StringReader(bos.toString()));

JsonElement result = resp.get("result");
JsonElement error = resp.get("error");


// ... etc
```

*Keep in mind I put these snippets together from existing JSON RPC client libraries, so this is not tested and may not compile as is, but should give you a good basis to work from.*

Answer (score -2):

JSON library usefule to make JSON objects:
http://www.json.org/java/ ,
Lib: http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

First thing is, JSON call will be AJAX call to some URL. The URL must return JSON content with content type set to "application/json".

You can make a new servlet, in response set above content type, Make new `JSONObject`, put your objects in it and write the `JSONObject.toString()` to response.

So the client will get the JSON String. You can access it using simple Javascript OR jQuery.

You can make a special servlet only for JSON support which only haqndles JSON AJAX requests and returns proper JSON responses.

parth.

Comment: This appears to be describing how to build a web service that receives requests and returns responses in JSON.  The questioner appears to be interested in how to consume a JSON RPC service from a plain Java application.

Comment: anyways... u also specified the same thing i specified... JSON.org :)